# The sum of entries of the matrix in the main diagonal

Tags: matrices

All the entries of the matrix $A$ are $0, 1,$ or $-1$, and it has exactly $2012$ nonzero entries.  Determine the sum of the entries in the main diagonal of the matrix $ A A^T$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trace of $AA^t$ is the sum of all squared elements of $A$. That is, the sum of $2012$ times $1$.